# Comment specific line using sed to python file

Tags: bash, shell

I want to comment specific line using shell script

My original python file (user.py)

```
import sys

def saying():
    sys.path.append('/home/tony')
    print(sys.path)
```

Note: I can not sure that there are only 4 whitespace. Maybe there will be 8 whitespace after project update.

I have to do `git pull` many times in a day, and later comment the line that include */homt/tony*, and then run my project.

My goal:

```
import sys

def saying():
    #sys.path.append('/home/tony')
    print(sys.path)
```

I have found many issues here, but there seems no related questions that has the Indentation.

I think my script step is:

1. Find '/home/tony' in which line, and save it to a variable v1
2. Search entire line that include '/home/tony', save it to another variable v2
3. Using `sed` to replace

```
### Step 1
v1=$(nl qq | grep '/home/tony' | awk '{print $1 " "}')   # GOT "3 "
v1=$((--${v1}))      # GOT "3"

### Step 2 (Still have no idea)
cat user.py | grep '[[:space:]]*/home/tony'  
# GOT "    sys.path.append('/home/tony')"

# But when I save it to variable
v2=$(cat user.py | grep '[[:space:]]*/home/tony')
echo ${v2}
# "sys.path.append('/home/tony')"   <---- Whitespace disappeared

### Step 3 (Still have no idea because I was blocked by Step 2)
```

Please help me, or if you have any other idea will be good.

Comment: `<---- Whitespace disappeared` because you used `${v2}` without quotes, which strips leading and trailing whitespaces. `v2` still contains whitespaces, which would be shown if you had used `echo "${v2}"`. That said as answers point out, your workflow seems to be needlessly complicated, you don't need to select a line with `grep` to edit it with `sed`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have to do git pull many times in a day, and later comment the line
>   that include /homt/tony, and then run my project.

I don't get it.

Anyway, you could simply use `sed` :

```
sed -i "s,sys.path.append('/home/tony'),#sys.path.append('/home/tony')," user.py
```

MacOS (you need to add `''` after -i option):

```
sed -i '' "s,sys.path.append('/home/tony'),#sys.path.append('/home/tony')," user.py
```

If the line could be something else than `sys.path.append('/home/tony')` (question unclear):

```
sed -i -E 's,(.*/home/tony.*),#\1,' user.py
```

If you need to place the `#` after the indent :

```
sed -i -E 's,([[:space:]]*)(.*/home/tony.*),\1#\2,' user.py
```

---

Since you used `awk`, an awk-based solution :

```
awk '/home\/tony/{$0="#"$0}1' user.py > temp && mv temps user.py
```

GNU awk > 4.1.0 (to directly replace the file):

```
awk -i inplace '/home\/tony/{$0="#"$0}1' user.py
```

Curious if someone finds a solution to place the `#` after the indent with awk (without using regexp)

EDIT :

Found it but I'd love to see a better one :

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]' '/home\/tony/{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){if($i){$i="#"$i; break}}}1' user.py
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I mean, there are user verification code in our project. I want to comment the verify part. So, I have to do `git reset HEAD^ --hard`, then `git pull`. After that, just start to comment the verify part in order to facilitate debugging.

Comment: and... after reading your answer, I have a good idea to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Is there only one sys.path.append?

If so you could try:

```
sed -i 's/sys.path.append/#sys.path.append/' user.py
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have many code to comment by this script. So sorry I did not describe my question clearly.